# Typedef NSArray of type in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

It has been a long time since I have worked in Objective C but now I am using it because I need to write something that will remain mostly source compatible for future versions. I want to create an init method that allows me to init my viewController with an array of my custom model object. In Swift I would do it like this:

```
typealias Stack = [StackBarTabItem]
…
func init(stacks:[Stack])
```

But how would I typedef an NSArray like that? I am pretty sure I can't do something like `typedef NSArray<StackBarTabItem> Stack;` so what is the syntax in objective c?

Comment: On iOS 9 generics type will be enabled! Until it will be released, `NSArray` will contain only `id` object type.

Answer (score 3):

Until iOS 9 and Xcode 7, this isn't officially supported. One way to do this is to subclass `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` and enforce typing in your subclass, but this isn't really recommended. One way to deal with the fact that `NSArray` can only hold `id`s is to use `respondsToSelector` before calling a method on any of the objects in the array.

This solution isn't really a substitute for a good typing system, but it's a common practice to get around this limitation. Thankfully, generic support is getting added soon!

Comment: Actually, I am running the beta. Where could I go to learn more about this?

Comment: I can't find a lot of information out there, but there's a bit under "Lightweight generics" in this Apple reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html

Comment: "Lightweight generics" are not added for akin of "better" Objective-C, but for Swift.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad but at least they add compilation level type checks and let you avoid type casting when accessing typed arrays.

Comment: Yes, there are type checks. Did you see my comments to the Q? – Type casting? Typically you do not need type casting, when using `id`. BTW: In autumn 2014 I said in a talk that instead of a static typed language Apple would do better, if they add the ability to annotate a type  to `NSArray` and still use a dynamic typed language. So I do not say that it is bad at all. But I think it is nearly unnecessary.

Comment: What about the ... typedef?

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is dynamically typed. You simply do not check for it.

Asking the audience on talks and in internet fora, the real danger that code will be shipped with a typing bug is minimal and by far lower than other sources of errors. Simply do not care about this.

Ask yourself: How could that happen without getting a runtime error at the very beginning of your next program run?

Comment: Well it's a small project I am planning on making open source. That method is public, and if people don't know that it needs to be an NSArray of a certain type of object they will get a runtime error.

Comment: Even it is a small and open source project, you should ship a documentation. However, as you said, the user will get a runtime error.

Comment: Yeah, I intend to, but it is always better to avoid these kinds of situations where the user can be affected by what would otherwise be an implementation detail.

Comment: When you use lightweight generics it is no implementation detail, too!?